# Angular - Trying to access value outside of $http get success and use it for a filter value

Tags: angularjs, angular-http, ngresource

I'm building a silly little Football app. On the first page, I am trying to load the country's top division standings and the coming week's fixtures.

I retrieve the data, using a RESTful Web Service and so is done *asynchronously*. The table is fine, but not the fixtures.

There is an array of fixture objects, within them, there's a 'matchday' and 'status' property. If you look at the 'this.getFixtures' function, look at the success code block. What I am trying to do is only display the fixtures for a certain match day. If there is one game left to be played on a certain matchday, then I only want that fixture displayed. If not, display next matchday's fixtures.

The 'status' property typically has a value of 'SCHEDULED' or 'FINISHED'. In the success code block I am saying:

Loop through all fixtures retrieved.
If this fixture is scheduled, that means, we're on the matchday for this fixture.
In which case, break loop.

I am then trying to use that value outside the get method, but I keep getting undefined. Is there any way to access that value outside the success block?

I'll use the $scope.matchDay function as the filter.This will help me to only display scheduled fixtures in that matchday with ng-repeat.

Anyway, sorry for the long winded post, but here's the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="grid-x">
<div class="medium-8 medium-offset-2 cell">
    <div id="premier-league-banner">
        <div class="banner-shade">
            <div class="grid-x">
                <div class="medium-5 cell">
                    <table>
                        <tr ng-repeat="team in premierLeagueTable.standing | limitTo: 6">
                            <th>{{ $index + 1 }}</th>
                            <td><img class="prem-thumbnail" src="{{ team.crestURI }}" /></td>
                            <th>{{ team.teamName }}</th>
                            <th>{{ team.playedGames }}</th>
                            <th>{{ team.goalDifference }}</th>
                            <th>{{ team.points }}</th>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="medium-2 cell">
                    <img src="images/prem-logo.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="medium-5 cell">
                    <table>
                        <tr ng-repeat="fixture in premierLeagueFixtures.fixtures | filter:{matchday: 10}">
                            <th>{{fixture.homeTeamName}}</th>
                            <td>vs</td>
                            <th>{{fixture.awayTeamName}}</th>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Angular JS

```
    // MODULE
var quickEleven = angular.module('quickEleven', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']);

// ROUTES
quickEleven.config(function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider

    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/home.htm',
        controller: 'homeController'
    })

});

// CONTROLLERS
quickEleven.controller('homeController', ['$scope', '$resource', '$log', 'footballData', function($scope, $resource, $log, footballData) {

    function getMonday(date) {
        var day = date.getDay() || 7;  
    if( day !== 1 ) 
        date.setHours(-24 * (day - 1)); 
        return date;
    }

    function convertDate(date) {
      var yyyy = date.getFullYear().toString();
      var mm = (date.getMonth()+1).toString();
      var dd  = date.getDate().toString();

      var mmChars = mm.split('');
      var ddChars = dd.split('');

      return yyyy + '-' + (mmChars[1]?mm:"0"+mmChars[0]) + '-' + (ddChars[1]?dd:"0"+ddChars[0]);
    }



    var thisMonday = getMonday(new Date);
    var nextMonday = getMonday(new Date);
    nextMonday.setDate(nextMonday.getDate() + 7);

    $log.info("Boom! " + convertDate(thisMonday));
    $log.info("For! " + convertDate(nextMonday));

    $scope.premierLeagueTable = footballData.getLeagueTable("http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/:competitionId/leagueTable", 445);
    //http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/:competitionId/fixtures?timeFrameStart=2018-03-01&timeFrameEnd=2018-03-05
    //"http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/:competitionId/fixtures/?matchday=9"
    $scope.premierLeagueFixtures = footballData.getFixtures("http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/:competitionId/fixtures?timeFrameStart=" + convertDate(thisMonday) + "&timeFrameEnd=" + convertDate(nextMonday), 445);
     $log.info($scope.premierLeagueFixtures);
     $log.info($scope.premierLeagueTable);

    $scope.matchdayValue = 9;

    $scope.matchDay = function() {
        return footballData.getMatchday();
    };

}]);


quickEleven.service('footballData', ['$resource', '$log', function($resource, $log) {

    //Referring to the latest matchday with the status as 'SCHEDULED'
    var self = this;
    var test;
    self.latestScheduledMatchday = 0;

    self.getMatchday = function() {
        $log.info("This is: " + test);
        return self.latestScheduledMatchday;
    }

    this.getLeagueTable = function (footballUrl, compId) {
        this.footballAPI = 
            $resource(footballUrl, {}, {    
                get: {
                    method: "GET",
                        headers: {
                            "X-Auth-Token": "f73808b698e84dccbe4886da3ea6e755"
                        }
                }
            })

            .get({
                competitionId: compId
            }, function(data) {
                this.fussball = data; 
            }, function(err) {
                $log.error(err);
            });

        return this.footballAPI;
    };



    this.getFixtures = function (footballUrl, compId) {
  //      var self;
        this.footballAPI = 
            $resource(footballUrl, {}, {    
                get: {
                    method: "GET",
                        headers: {
                            "X-Auth-Token": "f73808b698e84dccbe4886da3ea6e755"
                        }
                }
            })

            .get({
                competitionId: compId
            }, function(data) {
//                self = data.fixtures;
                self.latestScheduledMatchday = data.fixtures[0].matchday
                for (var i = 0; i < data.fixtures.length; i++) {
                    var fixture = data.fixtures[i];

                    if (fixture.status == 'SCHEDULED') {
                        test = fixture.matchday;
                        break;
                    } 
                }
                $log.info("Dollar signs... " + test);
            }, function(err) {
                $log.error(err);
            });

        return this.footballAPI;
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 issues so far. One on the note of undefined values is your service might not be getting implemented correctly. AFAIK you should be returning the service in the "function($resource, $log) {" function.

Here's how I'd change it (note I've not tested this)

```
quickEleven.service('footballData', ['$resource', '$log', function($resource, $log) {

  //Referring to the latest matchday with the status as 'SCHEDULED'
  var wrappedService = {};
  var test;
  var latestScheduledMatchday = 0;

  var getMatchday = function() {
      $log.info("This is: " + test);
      return latestScheduledMatchday;
  }

  wrappedService.getLeagueTable = function (footballUrl, compId) {
      wrappedService.footballAPI = 
          $resource(footballUrl, {}, {    
              get: {
                  method: "GET",
                      headers: {
                          "X-Auth-Token": "f73808b698e84dccbe4886da3ea6e755"
                      }
              }
          })

          .get({
              competitionId: compId
          }, function(data) {
              wrappedService.fussball = data; 
          }, function(err) {
              $log.error(err);
          });

      return wrappedService.footballAPI;
  };



  wrappedService.getFixtures = function (footballUrl, compId) {
      wrappedService.footballAPI = 
          $resource(footballUrl, {}, {    
              get: {
                  method: "GET",
                      headers: {
                          "X-Auth-Token": "f73808b698e84dccbe4886da3ea6e755"
                      }
              }
          })

          .get({
              competitionId: compId
          }, function(data) {
              latestScheduledMatchday = data.fixtures[0].matchday
              for (var i = 0; i < data.fixtures.length; i++) {
                  var fixture = data.fixtures[i];

                  if (fixture.status == 'SCHEDULED') {
                      test = fixture.matchday;
                      break;
                  } 
              }
              $log.info("Dollar signs... " + test);
          }, function(err) {
              $log.error(err);
          });

      return wrappedService.footballAPI;
  };
  return wrappedService;
}]);
```

So instead of the function returning no service, you have your service wrapped and returned as I believe you were intending. I also removed references to "self" since your intention there (internal service variables) is more eloquently handled with var scoping in the function.

Second issue that you will see once your service is working.

```
    $scope.premierLeagueTable = footballData.getLeagueTable("http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/:competitionId/leagueTable", 445);
```

This line does not return the request data, but returns the request object. In fact by the time $scope.premierLeagueTable is set, the request hasn't even completed yet. What you do get is access to a promise that you can put a callback function in. See the angular resource documentation for more info, specifically the third example in the user-resource section where you see .$promise https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource#user-resource.

Whatever functionality you want to apply the data return to should live inside that .$promise.then(...) callback. I'm not entirely sure if the promise in there receives the response data, or your callback return. You'll have to read further or experiment to find that out.